# set a ui to allow to nodes interact via smartpy contract

Tags: rpc, smartpy

Hii  have wrote a smart contract using smartpy where i have two nodes that should interact with each other, now i want to set the user interface to simulate the nodes interact what should i use and how please.

Comment: Nodes can't really interact with each other in that way. Do you mean two smart contracts that should interact with each other? If you want to simluate onchain transactions you can use try-michelson: http://try-michelson.com

Answer (score 3):

Give ConseilJS a try.

Here’s a set of tutorials:

https://medium.com/the-cryptonomic-aperiodical/blockchain-development-with-tezos-698aa930e50f

If you just want straight code samples, check this out:

https://gist.github.com/anonymoussprocket/148d82fc9bf6c413be04155a90d57be6

Comment: thank you, i used conseilJs to access the contract, how can i access the contract storage and if the contract has to display a message how can do that please? and how can i call the contract but in specific entrypoint (method)?